# Unity inspector does not display XML docs (<summary>) as tooltip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xmldocument

Unity does not display XML documentation comments(or the  tag),  as tool tip. I am 90% sure it did before. The below code does not show any tool tip when hovering over the "testBool". It only shows a tool tip when you add [Tooltip("tip")] attribute to "testBool".

I tried using a brand new unity project, updating unity and visual studio, using both visual studio 2019 and 2017, making the "testBool" public instead of adding [SerializeField] attribute but none of it worked.

Is there a fix for this or unity never displays summaries as tooltips?

```
/// <summary>
/// unity does not display this summary when hovering over testBool but visual studio displays when hovering over it.
/// </summary>
[SerializeField] bool testBool;
```

Unity versions tried: 2019.4.7f1, 2019.4.0f1
Visual studio versions tried: visual studio 2019 16.7.0 and an older one; visual studio 2017 15.9.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only add tooltips using [Tooltip("your text goes here")]. A [similiar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164242/using-c-summary-documentation-as-tooltip-in-unity) on GameDev StackExchange comes to the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will confirm this on a friends computer and close the question